# Reference data from current owner of relationship with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have these to models

```
class ExerciseSolving < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :exercise

    attr_accessor :important_data
end

class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :exercise_solvings

    def start
        #1
    end
end
```

How can I reference the current `ExerciseSolving` at *#1*, when I call attributes like this:

```
ExerciseSolving.first.exercise.start
```

I need `:important_data` from the current relationship inside of the described function. Is there a clean way to to this? Directly passing the `ExerciseSolving` instance to `Exercise` seems dirty to me.

Comment: just capture the solving `@exercise_solving = ExerciseSolving.first` and then reference the `exercise` later. Beyond that we need a little more detail as to implementation because the question is not so clear on this part.

Answer (score 0):

try to adhere to the [law of demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) and encapsulate the behavior:

```
class ExerciseSolving < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :exercise

  attr_accessor :important_data

  def start
    exercise.solve(important_data)
  end
end

class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exercise_solvings

  def solve(data)
    [...]
  end
end

@exercise_solving = ExerciseSolving.first
@exercise_solving.start
```